# How to "connectToHost:" and "acceptOnPort:" on same GCDAsyncSocket object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcdasyncsocket, gcdasyncudpsocket

I'm trying to "**send to**" and "**receive from**" on same GCDAsyncSocket object, but it return's error as `Attempting to accept while connected or accepting connections. Disconnect first.` while trying to initialising the object.

My Code :

```
-(instancetype)initWithHost:(NSString *)host port:(NSInteger)port userData:(NSDictionary *)userData delegate:(id<AKSenderSocketDelegate>)delegate
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self)
  {
     self.delegate = delegate;
     self.senderSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
     self.senderSocket.userData = userData;

    NSError *err = nil;

    //---- Sender
    if (![self.senderSocket connectToHost:host onPort:port error:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to connect: %@", err);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connected to :%@:%ld",host,(long)port);
    }

    //---- Listener
    if (![self.senderSocket acceptOnPort:0 error:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open lintening port. :%@",err.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Listening to port :%hu and host :%@",self.senderSocket.localPort,self.senderSocket.localHost);
    }
  }
   return self;
}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You're overcooking the pudding (grin). Once you've connected, you're ready to start communicating. There's no need for the accept message.

`connectToHost:onPort:error:` is like placing a phone call: you call, the other party picks up (because that other party has *already* made itself available with `acceptOnPort:error:` or its equivalent). Once the connection is made, you can read *and* write data over the same socket; sockets are bi-directional.

So if you want to "place a call", use `connectToHost:onPort:error:`. If instead you want to wait for the other party to place the call, use `acceptOnPort:error:`. Regardless of which side of the conversation is the "connecter" or the "accepter", both sides of the conversation can both send (write) and listen (read).